# Facebook PHP SDK Getting Expiration date on Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having a problem where a user's access tokens will expire, but the session hasn't leading to certain api calls throwing an exception.

I was hoping to be able to somehow call the access token's expiration data directly, or at least some clean way of telling if the access token I'm using has already expired without having to first try an api call and catch the exception and read the error message.

Right now, in pseudo code I have

```
try {
    $permissions = getFBPerms();  # this seems to work fine even with expired tokens
    doFBApiCall(); # this will throw an exception withe expired tokens
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    var_dump($e); # this usually comes out to expired tokens
}
```

I want to be able to

```
if (checkFBTokenStatus())
    // do everything with no worries
else 
    gotoFBLoginUrl(); # re-log them in to get new access tokens
```

I also want a clean solution which I can adapt easily in case a user changed passwords, they authorized the app etc. I'm currently working off of [this blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/) but I dislike the way it works and it doesn't really make sense. Furthermore, I'm hoping they've updated the mechanism since that blog post was put up. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
try {
    $permissions = getFBPerms();  # this seems to work fine even with expired tokens
    doFBApiCall(); # this will throw an exception withe expired tokens
    // Do whatever you want...
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    gotoFBLoginUrl(); # re-log them in to get new access tokens
}
```

?

Of course, you can make a call to, for example, `/me` to check whether the token is valid, but that will imply executing one extra call before each API call, that doesn't make much sense..

Also, I wouldn't rely on expiration date (tokens should least 3 hours from creation), since it might not be **exact**. Correct way is to catch the exception and *then* redirect the user to login page.

Or, the brutal way, ask for tokens that doesn't expire :)

### UPDATE: The deauthorize callback

if you go in the "Advanced" pane of you app settings, you'll find the "Deauthorize callback" field, in which you can insert an URL that is pinged when an user deauthorizes your app. This way, you have a certain way to tell whether an user removed your app.

[image]

Comment: That's the way I have it set up now. The only thing is, sometimes the user removed my app, and I don't want to bombard them with requests when they're not necessary. Imagine you removed an app. Then you tried doing something that should work even without Facebook, only to be asked for facebook approval. It would be very annoying.

Comment: Ok, now I understand where's your point.. So, the user is not logged in via facebook, but could connect to facebook if he wants? I guess the best thing to do would be to add a check to see whether the user wants to connect or not. There should be a way to check if an user removed your application (have a look at FB docs), you can check that before redirecting to FB login.

Comment: Or, as I said before, if you ask for the `offline_access` permission, you will be given an access token that never expires.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I knew about offline_access, but really wanted to avoid that if at all possible, since I always hated it when apps asked me for it. Also, it didn't deal with some of the deeper issues I had which prevented me from just re asking for authorization constantly. I've decided to try to deal with this issue by checking cookies and login times. Not a perfect solution, but usable.